# .env file not getting sourced in Alpine Linux Docker

Tags: bash, docker

`.env` file is in project root.
I am using a docker file as follows

```sh
FROM alpine:3.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN apk update && apk add build-base python3 python3-dev --no-cache bash &&  \
   pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
   pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --no-cache-dir -e. && \
   ./scripts/install.sh

EXPOSE 5000 3306
CMD ["myserver", "run"]
```

and the install.sh file as follows

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source .env
```

When I log in to the docker container I noticed that the `.env` file not getting sourced. How ever `.env` file is in the `folder`.  How to source the `.env` file in docker container by using the docker file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RUN` just effect in build stage, so you `source` will never affect container which is run time. You should do source in `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` which will run in container run time, write a `entrypoint.sh` for your project. Something like [this](https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/blob/5a60b96907bd967e57d1b6611be811d000c2a1b2/3.8-rc/ubuntu/Dockerfile)

**Dockerfile:**

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh:**

```
source .env
my_server run
```

And, use `ENV` in dockerfile is another way which will affect the runtime container.

Comment: better to add stripped down example in your answer than link to a file

Comment: Still I didnt see the variables from .env file even after executing printenv  from inside the docker container @atline

Comment: I guess you use `docker exec` to enter into the container, but this cannot prove that it not work. As `source` in `docker-entrypoint.sh` just affect this shell session & its subprocess. So when you use `docker exec -it xxx /bin/bash` to enter the container, you can not see it. You should add `printenv` in docker-entrypoint.sh, then use docker logs to see it, and it will affect your `my_server run`. If you want also see it when exec, then explicit use ENV in dockerfile is the way, these variable will persist into container.